# How to select all children in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Lets say I have a wrapper for some big UI element with `class="wrapper"`.

The HTML would be like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   / a lot of other elements
</div>
```

Now I need to select each of elements and I go like this:

```
.wrapper > .first_element_class{}
.wrapper > .second_element_class{}
...
```

Is there a way to select all wrappers children with one line? Something like this:

```
.wrapper{
   .first_class{}
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your "Something like this" doesn't look like a one-liner to me.

Answer (score 17):

you can use the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) `*` if you don't know which element/class you will have

Something like this:

```css
.wrapper>* {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">this is red</div>
  <span>this is red</span>
  <section>this is red</section>
</div>
```

Comment: How about all offsprings?

Answer (score 6):

You can use white space to match all descendants of an element.

```
.wrapper * {
  color: black;
}
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors

Note, this would select all the children and their grandchildren recursively if that is what you need. Could be quite an expensive operation depending on how much markup elements you nested into `.wrapper`.